# Promela SPIN unreached in proctype error

Tags: cygwin, mutual-exclusion, model-checking, spin, promela

I'm pretty new to SPIN and Promela and I came across this error when I'm trying to verify the liveness property in my models.

Error code:

```
unreached in proctype P
        (0 of 29 states)
unreached in proctype monitor
        mutex_assert.pml:39, state 1, "assert(!((mutex>1)))"
        mutex_assert.pml:42, state 2, "-end-"
        (2 of 2 states)
unreached in init
        (0 of 3 states)
unreached in claim ltl_0
        _spin_nvr.tmp:10, state 13, "-end-"
        (1 of 13 states)

pan: elapsed time 0 seconds
```

The code is basically an implementation of Peterson's algorithm and I checked for safety and it seems to be valid. But whenever I try to validate the liveness property using the ltl {[]((wait -> <> (cs)))}, it comes up with the above errors. I'm not sure what they mean so I don't know how to proceed...

My code is as follows:

```
#define N 3
#define wait   (P[1]@WAIT)
#define cs     (P[1]@CRITICAL)

int pos[N]; 
int step[N]; 
int enter;
byte mutex;
ltl {[]((wait -> <> (cs)))}

proctype P(int i) {
  int t;
  int k;
  WAIT:
  for (t : 1 .. (N-1)){
  pos[i] = t
  step[t] = i
  k = 0;
  do
  ::  atomic {(k != i && k < N && (pos[k] < t|| step[t] != i)) -> k++}
  ::  atomic {k == i -> k++}
  ::  atomic {k == N -> break}
  od;
  }

CRITICAL:
  atomic {mutex++;
  printf("MSC: P(%d) HAS ENTERED THE CRITICAL SECTION.\n", i);
  mutex--;}
  pos[i] = 0;
}

init {
  atomic { run P(0); }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**General Answer**

This is a **warning** telling you that *some states are unreachable* due to transitions that are never taken.

In general, this is **not** an **error**, but it is a **good practice** to take a close look to the unreachable states for *every routine that you modelled*, and check that you expect none of them to be reachable. *i.e. in the case the model is not correct wrt. the intended behaviour*.

**Note.** You can use the label **end:** in front of a particular line of code to mark valid terminating states, so to get rid of those warnings, *e.g. when your procedure does not terminate*. More info [here](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/end.html).

---

**Specific Answer**

I can not reproduce your output. In particular, by running

```
~$ spin -a file.pml
~$ gcc pan.c
~$ ./a.out -a
```

I get the following output, which is different from yours:

```
(Spin Version 6.4.3 -- 16 December 2014)
    + Partial Order Reduction

Full statespace search for:
    never claim             + (ltl_0)
    assertion violations    + (if within scope of claim)
    acceptance   cycles     + (fairness disabled)
    invalid end states  - (disabled by never claim)

State-vector 64 byte, depth reached 47, errors: 0
       41 states, stored (58 visited)
       18 states, matched
       76 transitions (= visited+matched)
        0 atomic steps
hash conflicts:         0 (resolved)

Stats on memory usage (in Megabytes):
    0.004   equivalent memory usage for states (stored*(State-vector + overhead))
    0.288   actual memory usage for states
  128.000   memory used for hash table (-w24)
    0.534   memory used for DFS stack (-m10000)
  128.730   total actual memory usage


unreached in proctype P
    (0 of 29 states)
unreached in init
    (0 of 3 states)
unreached in claim ltl_0
    _spin_nvr.tmp:10, state 13, "-end-"
    (1 of 13 states)

pan: elapsed time 0 seconds
```

In particular, I lack the warnings about the unreached states in the **monitor** process. As far as I am concerned, juding from the source code, none of the warnings I obtained is problematic.

Either you are using a different version of **Spin** than me, or you did not include the full source code in your question. In the latter case, could you edit your question and add the code? I'll update my answer afterwards.

---

**EDIT**: in the comments, you ask what does the following message mean: *"unreached in claim ltl_0 _spin_nvr.tmp:10, state 13, "-end-"*".

If you open the file **_spin_nvr.tmp**, you can see the following piece of **Promela** code, which corresponds to a **Büchi automaton** that accepts all and only the execution which violate your ltl property *[]((wait -> <> (cs)))*.

```
never ltl_0 {    /* !([] ((! ((P[1]@WAIT))) || (<> ((P[1]@CRITICAL))))) */
T0_init:
    do
    :: (! ((! ((P[1]@WAIT)))) && ! (((P[1]@CRITICAL)))) -> goto accept_S4
    :: (1) -> goto T0_init
    od;
accept_S4:
    do
    :: (! (((P[1]@CRITICAL)))) -> goto accept_S4
    od;
}
```

The message simply warns you that the execution of this code will never reach the last closing bracket **}** (state *"-end-"*), meaning that the procedure does never terminate.

Comment: Thank you so much! Yeah, I edited my code one last time before posting it on here and that seemed to have fixed it. What does the code below mean though? I assumed it was part of the error?

unreached in claim ltl_0
    _spin_nvr.tmp:10, state 13, "-end-"

Comment: @firearian I updated my post to answer your question. Again, please be sure to understand that there is **no error** there.

Comment: Thank you so much! That answers my question! A small followup though, if I may. Am I to understand that this means the ltl property is verified successfully because the process never enters the "never ltl_0"?

Comment: @firearian To verify that a model **M** satisfies an LTL formula **F**, **Spin**  generates a **Buchi Automata** corresponding to the negation of **F**, and computes its **synchronous product** with the **Automata** of **M** *[I'm simplifying a bit]*. If the latter product contains an **acceptance cycle**, then you have a counter-example to your property **F**. Otherwise, your system is safe. In general, it is not strictly speaking relevant if you execute some transitions of the **Buchi Automata**, but rather whether you have an execution over an accepting path.

Comment: So, focusing on your example, it means that no execution of the synchronous product of your model **M** + *never ltl_0* ever goes to the state labelled **accept_S4**. However, the execution still goes through the state with the code *:: (1) -> goto T0_init* (it loops over it).

Comment: Thanks so much! Do you know ant documents I can read to understand this further in depth? While I do understand what you mean I'd like to also learn why and how it works. Thanks again!

Comment: @firearian Short Presentations: http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/ Books: http://spinroot.com/spin/books.html and Papers: http://spinroot.com/spin/theory.html